# How to use React props in Tailwind component

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I'm trying to create a simple button component in a Next App using Tailwind CSS where I'm passing some values as background, color, etc in the button props and I want to get this values in my component and then render my button with that props. I've more than one type of button in my app.

That's my colors options:

```js
export type ColorOptions =
  | "light"
  | "primary"
  | "secondary"
  | "terciary"
  | "details";
```

Here is my button component:

```js
import { ButtonHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import { ColorOptions, FontOptions } from "@/app/@types/theme";

type ButtonNativeProps = ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

type ButtonProps = ButtonNativeProps & {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  onClick: () => void;
  color?: ColorOptions;
  background?: ColorOptions;
  font?: FontOptions;
  fontSize?: string;
  icon?: React.ReactNode;
  styleProps?: string;
};

export default function Button({
  children,
  onClick,
  color = "light",
  background = "terciary",
  font = "main",
  fontSize = "xl",
  icon,
  styleProps,
  ...props
}: ButtonProps) {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={onClick}
      className={`font-${font} bg-${background}-100 text-${color}-100 text-${fontSize} flex flex-row px-6 py-3 rounded-small font-bold tracking-wide transition hover:bg-${background}-75 animation ${styleProps}`}
      {...props}
    >
      {children}
      {icon}
    </button>
  );
}
```

And my `tailwind.config.js`

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        light: {
          100: "#FFFFFF",
        },
        primary: {
          100: "#383436",
          75: "rgba(56, 52, 54, 0.75)",
          50: "rgba(56, 52, 54, 0.5)",
        },
        secondary: {
          100: "#3891A6",
          75: "rgba(56, 145, 166, 0.75)",
          50: "rgba(56, 145, 166, 0.5)",
        },
        terciary: {
          100: "#DB5461",
          75: "rgba(219, 84, 97, 0.75)",
          50: "rgba(219, 84, 97, 0.5)",
        },
        details: {
          100: "#61ED46",
          75: "rgba(97, 237, 70, 0.75)",
          50: "rgba(97, 237, 70, 0.5)",
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        title: ["Jost", "serif"],
        main: ["Nunito Sans", "serif"],
        code: ["Fira Code", "sans-serif"],
      },
      borderRadius: {
        small: "0.625rem",
        large: "1.25rem",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
  darkMode: "class",
};
```

I'm having the following first result
[Initial return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EDq8.png)

But if I put a value in the button component as here my result just disappears

```js
<Button background="details" onClick={() => {}} />
```

[My component don't have the background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WApyF.png)

The worst is that the class is present in my html element, as we can check on browser's elements tree.[Classes in my component with correctly values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ6Xd.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider:

- Using full class names in the props, like:

  ```js
  export default function Button({
    children,
    onClick,
    color = "text-light-100",
    background = "bg-terciary-100 hover:bg-terciary-75",
    font = "font-main",
    fontSize = "text-xl",
    icon,
    styleProps,
    ...props
  }: ButtonProps) {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`${font} ${background} ${color} ${fontSize} flex flex-row px-6 py-3 rounded-small font-bold tracking-wide transition animation ${styleProps}`}
  ```
- Using class maps:

  ```
  const COLOR = {
    light: 'text-light-100',
    …
  };

  const BACKGROUND = {
    terciary: 'bg-terciary-100 hover:bg-terciary-75',
    …
  };

  const FONT = {
    main: 'font-main',
    …
  };

  const FONT_SIZE = {
    xl: 'text-xl',
    …
  };

  export default function Button({
    children,
    onClick,
    color = "light",
    background = "terciary",
    font = "main",
    fontSize = "xl",
    icon,
    styleProps,
    ...props
  }: ButtonProps) {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={onClick}
        className={`${FONT[font]} ${BACKGROUND[background]} ${COLOR[color]} ${FONT_SIZE[fontSize]} flex flex-row px-6 py-3 rounded-small font-bold tracking-wide transition animation ${styleProps}`}
  ```
- Using [`safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) in your Tailwind configuration:

  ```js
  /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
  module.exports = {
    …
    safelist: [
      { pattern: /^(bg|text)-.+-100$/ },
      { pattern: /^bg-.+-75$/, variants: ['hover'] },
      { pattern: /^font-(title|main|code|sans|sans-serif|mono)$/ },
      { pattern: /^text-(xs|sm|base|lg|[0-9]?xl)$/ },
    ],
  }
  ```